# sort dask dataframes by multiple columns some ascending, some descending

Tags: pandas, sorting, dataframe, dask

Im converting `pandas` to `dask`, main problem so far is sorting.

For converting simple sorts Im using `nlargest` for complex sorting, like:

```
df = df.sort_values(
            by=['column_1', 'column_2', 'column_3', 'column_4', 'column_5', 'column_6', 'column_7'],
            ascending=[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        )
```

Im converting to pandas and then back to dask: `dd.from_pandas`

for this:
`ar = ar.sort_values(by=['column_1', 'column_2'], ascending=[1, 0])`

I don't know what to do

Im assuming converting to **pandas** and back to **dask** slows down things (no idea how terrible it is)

Can `nlargest` handle this? I don't see how to achieve one column descending and the other ascending.

Answer (score 3):

Trying to expand the conversation: Maybe it is not about replacing `sort_values` but re writing the whole thing in a `dask` friendly way:

After:

`ar = ar.sort_values(by=['column_1', 'column_2'], ascending=[1, 0])`

came:

`ar = ar.groupby(['column_1']).first()`

These two line could be re written in one `dask` friendly line:

`ar = ar.groupby(['column_1']).agg({'column_2': 'max'})`

I don't consider this an answer to the question, still looking for ways to deal with `sort_values`, maybe there are multiple ways.